# Detect windows service failure

Tags: windows, service, detection, status

Is it possible for one windows service to detect whether one of the other running windows services have stopped?

For some reason, 3rd party services are sometimes stopping, and I have to manually start them again. I need a service to automate this annoying process.

Comment: In the Services control panel, check out the "Recovery" tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would strongly advise you target your efforts on correcting the issues diagnosed instead of fire-fighting the symptoms. Find out *why* the third party services are stopping / failing and nip the issues in the bud.

However, if you must implement something in the time being, take a look at `ServiceController`, with information found at [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx). This will allow you to query services, their states, and further *control* them, as in calling `Start`, as required, for your particular case.

Assuming (maybe against better judgement) that your'e using .NET, and, due to my affinity to it, C# as the language, consider the following for a quick off-the-cuff example:

```
//Add a reference to System.ServiceProcess

using System.ServiceProcess;

var services = ServiceController.GetServices();
foreach (var service in services)
{
    if (service.ServiceName == myServiceName &&
        service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
    {
        service.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up implementing something that closely resembles your solution, I just wondered if there is a way to "listen" to status changes for a particular service.

Implemented solution uses polling in time intervals.

Thanks for suggestions.